# Angular 8 Display variable inside a variable in a template

Tags: angular6, angular8

[image]
I have tried to escape the `"{{ }}"` in the string stored on my DB, used the ASCII character instead of the curly braces, put it inside `[innerHTML]` but the result was always the same.

Do you know how can I solve this?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You want to show data from an object using there key and value,
first see in which form your data is coming, for example:-
suppose u have an object: 
`this.data = {'title': 'XYZ'}` in your .ts file then you can show output like this: 
`<p>{{data.title}}</p>` and output will be `XYZ`